# Nothing Displayed in web page with Angular clearly showing data in an array

Tags: javascript, asp.net, angularjs, arrays, ajax

Not sure what is going on ,  but I'm not getting anything to display on my web page with ng-repeat with template.

**Here is a picture image showing the data**

[This pic shows my console.log output with array of objects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsmCS.png)

**NO IDEA why doesn't just display on the web page!**

```
Devices:  Array[17] 
  0 : Object
    Aid :  "....."
    ...
  1 : Object
```

**Angular controller with function**

```
(function () {
  'use strict';

  angular.module('app').controller('DeviceController', DeviceController);

        function DeviceController($http){
            var vm = this;
            var dataService = $http;
            //dataService.get("/api/Product")

            vm.devices = [];

        deviceList();

        function deviceList() {
            dataService.get("http://localhost:42822/api/device")
            .then(function (result) {
                vm.devices = result.data;
                //debugger;
                console.log(vm.devices);
            },
            function (error) {
                handleException(error);
            });
        }


        function handleException(error) {
            alert(error.data.ExceptionMessage);
        }

  }



 })();
```

**HTML**

```
<html>

<head> </head>

<body>
    <div ng-app="app" ng-controller="DeviceController as vm">
            <div>test</div><br>

        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr ng-repeat="device in vm.devices">
                    <td>{{device.Aid}}</td>
                    <td>{{device.DeviceId}}</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>


    </div>
</body>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>

<!--<script src="~/Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>-->
<script src="./app/app.module.js"></script>
<script src="./app/device.controller.js"></script>



</html>
```

**NO IDEA why doesn't just display on the web page!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have data inside `Devices` object of response, then you need to change your assignment in ajax resolve like below.

```
vm.devices = result.data.Devices;
```

I'd suggest you to change your response from server, instead of sending `Devices` collection in `Devices` object, directly send it in response.

---

**OR** you could also make changes on HTML directly, but it wouldn't be good way to go.

```
<tr ng-repeat="device in vm.devices.Devices">
    <td>{{device.Aid}}</td>
    <td>{{device.DeviceId}}</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Nice !   that worked .    1. This looks UGLY to me,  is that standard or should i changed something in my code to fix this  ,   again thank you so much

Comment: @CodingAway it would be awesome if you return `Devices` collection directly in the response..

Comment: Ok wait ,  it "works with vm.devices.Devices ,   but i did not change to have  result.data.Devices    -    If I DID change to result.data.Devices,  then would I be able to just do   device in vm.devices  ?

Comment: @CodingAway yes, thats why I had separator between those two way, 1st one appropriate.. don't go for 2nd one(its just for demo)

Comment: Ok, thx so much    -  real quick ,..  this data comes from a Web Api service call,   so  how can i achieve this on my end (client)?   " if you return Devices collection directly in the response.. "       Does this have to be done on the server side ?    thx

Comment: @CodingAway if you could do it on server side then it would be awesome. then you don't need to fix anything on client side.. code will be like `vm.devices = result.data;` that you were doing initially..

Comment: on the call the the server,  I simply call this URL locally   http://localhost:42822/api/device    so I gather that it is how the data is being sent from the ms web api method, right ?